# Try & Catch not working when using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, try-catch

There's a strange issue in my script.
I'm invoking a command on some servers. If I can't connect to the server (because it's offline or something) I still want to log that (Server is offline > log.txt)

Apparently, when an error occurs in `Try` block, the `Catch` block is not executed.

To test this, I wrote a value to the `ComputerName` parameter that doesn't exist.
Here's my code:

```
Try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName hui -ScriptBlock $sb
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Hello"
}
```

But the Script never puts out "Hello"

The exception I get is a `PSRemotingTransportException`. I also tried to specify the exception, also didn't work

When I set a breakpoint at the `Invoke-Command` line, it also ignores the catch block. Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not a terminating error, so it will never be caught by `try`/`catch`. Add `-ErrorAction Stop`:

```
Try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName hui -ScriptBlock $sb -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very informative since i never really got what I was supposed to do with the `-ErrorAction` Parameter. Works like a charm now!